# Add Facebook OG action/object and comments into interactive website

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to Facebook OG, its a great idea to add OG support to a social website to have certain interactions with Facebook.

Ok here is what I've figured out so far:
1) All OG meta tags are set correctly on the website
2) Tested with debugger, and retrieving all the correct information canonically
3) Created one OG action and one OG object intended to be used when a user makes a new post on the website, it would update in his Facebook feed as well.

Here is what I'm stuck with:

I got the OG codes from the developers section:
Action:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/cooking:cook?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
item=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F612460332144487
```

Object:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/product.item?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
object=%7B%22og%3Aurl%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fsamples.ogp.me%5C%2F612460332144487%22%2C%22og%3Atitle%22%3A%22Sample+Item%22%2C%22og%3Atype%22%3A%22product.item <blah blah blah>
```

How would I integrate the OG action/object so that my website will send a signal to OG whenever a user creates a new post?

Side Question: is there a way to add a comment box in a popup photo (with canonical urls intact so comments are seperated from each photo)

Thanks a bunch if someone can guide me to the right way!

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “sending a signal to OG”. You should probably simply use self-hosted objects – meaning, by having the OG meta data inside your posts on your website, they themselves _are_ the Open Graph objects. // To have individual comment boxes for each photo, you also need an individual URL for each photo (not the image URL itself, but a dedicated HTML document that again contains the OG meta info for that photo.)

Comment: yes each photo has its own unique url, and og is getting the right urls.. but comments are still all showing up everywhere.. I believe its due to the photos being opened inside a popup lightbox install of a full html page..

Comment: ok lol i was always under the impression, the website needed to somehow sends action signals to the facebook og app in order for the action/object to be posted on the feed? the OG meta are all working (placed inside header) I saw a "get code" button beside each action and object... would i need to put these snippets somewhere on the website?

Comment: for example: http://dev16.thinqcloud.com/photos/e4e6107e71e13714c0a38dc9c44db640 - the OG URL checks out fine, all meta data is detected correctly.. but for some reason the facebook comment is still not being individualized for that photo?

Comment: Yes, if you want to _publish_ an Open Graph story for the user, you either have to present them with the Share dialog, or make an API call in their name (the latter requires them to log into your app and grant publishing permission first) – that’s all explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#publish

Comment: thanks I understand the sharing part, that works fine. The 2nd part is what i want to do... yes we already have "login via facebook" for the website..  so after we grant publishing permission (in the app I'm assuming?) are we all set? thanks

Comment: You’ll need to get your use of the permission reviewed by Facebook as well, before you can ask common users for it.

Comment: ok been digging around, I think I'm done everything necessary.. just want to double-check here: 1) App credited 2) Action/Object created in OG 3) Action publishing permission given 4) action/object meta added (see below) Conclusion: do I now need to insert the action/object code snippets (posted above) somewhere in the header of the website? And the code FB supplied is not php ready, what is the exact format, are there examples somewhere? thanks so much! getting there!

Comment: meta added: <meta property="graph:item" content="{value}"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="product.item"> (not sure what to put for action content?)

Comment: The action does not go into OG meta data, those are only to specify the details of the object – the action is what you “undertake” with/upon the object. And the code you can get from Open Graph section in app dashboard is available for the PHP SDK as well, you just have to choose “Platform” PHP from the dropdown in the modal.